# Is there a way to list all fields for a file on the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have a simple issue. When I request `root as parent or sharedWithMe = true` the result I get has less folders than when I request `root as parent` and `sharedWithMe = true` separately. I have yet to find the difference between the folders that show up on the single query but fail to show up on the combined query.

My hope is that if I query all the fields then maybe I will be able to tell the difference. Is there a way to do that? or is there maybe a playground for the Google Drive API where I can test different queries?

This is the code that returns less folders than it should:

```
val response =
 gDriveClient.files()
 .list()
 .setSpaces("drive")
 .setCorpora("user")
 .setFields("files(id, name, size, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents, quotaBytesUsed),nextPageToken")
 .setQ("('root' in parents or sharedWithMe = true) and trashed = false")
 .setSupportsAllDrivers(true)
```

And if I run `.setQ("('root' in parents) and trashed = false")` and `.setQ("(sharedWithMe = true) and trashed = false")` then I get more results than the code above it. Some of the shared folders are the ones that I'm missing.

Thanks.

**EDIT: Just want to clarify, the correct answer below is * to get all field. The answer to my actual issue, not getting all items, is that I am not setting `pageSize` and it is limited to 100 by default.**

Comment: Sounds like a bug i would submit it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return all the fields set fields equal to *

```
.setFields("*")
```

As for your issue it sounds like a bug to me you might want to consider submitting a report Sounds like a bug i would submit it to the [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think to put a *. I will try a few more things before submitting a bug, thanks.

Comment: I cant believe that v3 doent just return everything by default but forces use to use fields.  

Comment: * did work for me, not sure it got me everything but it got a lot of stuff. Turns out the issue was page size.